# R topicmodels package: How to set the parameter of Beta (eta) when we do LDA?

Tags: r, topic-modeling, topicmodels

Using the R package `topicmodels` and function `LDA()`, how can one set the Beta (or eta)?

I know we can set the Alpha parameter by writing `control=list(alpha = 0.5)` in the LDA command, but `eta=` does not work.

Moreover, what is the default value of eta in `topicmodels`?

Answer (score 0):

In `topicmodels`, the eta parameter described in theoretical papers is called delta.

```
lda <- LDA(dtm, control = list(delta = 0.6), k = K)
```

> the default 0.1 is suggested in Griffiths and Steyvers (2004).

Source: [package vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/topicmodels/vignettes/topicmodels.pdf)